# Meu site está dando como falso (fraude, phishing), como resolver?

Tags: domínio

Tenho o domínio [www.elmocorretordeimoveis.com.br](http://www.elmocorretordeimoveis.com.br) e está dando como *falso*, alterei o até a hospedagem mas nada resolve.

Comment: Eu busquei no PhishTank e parece que alguém estava hospedando uma página falsa (phishing) do Yahoo: https://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=3704803

Comment: Existe uma empresa chamada Sucuri (https://sucuri.net/website-antivirus/blacklist-removal-and-repair) que oferece esses tipos de serviços, além de monitor futuros blacklists, quedas do site, alteração de dns (...). Sim, eu utilizo. Mas é pago anualmente.

Comment: tente instalar um protocolo de segurança

Comment: Este domínio hospedou malware, então vc deve limpar e pedir reconsideração nos serviços online. É gratuito e simples, basta uma pesquisada na web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o link:

> https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/kb/como-funciona-protecao-phishing-e-software-malicioso?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Para solicitar a remoção da lista de fraudes preencha os seguintes formulários:

- Remoção da lista de malwares: https://www.stopbadware.org/request-review
- Remoção da lista de pishing: https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/

Então é só aguardar, não existe previsão.

---

Parece que a empresa que relatou o problema foi a [NetCraft](http://www.netcraft.com) e fazendo uma busca em http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.elmocorretordeimoveis.com.br o grau de risco é de 10/10 (nivel máximo), isto pode ter sido algum "problema" com o antigo administrador pois o site atual parece estar vinculado (dns) com o [websitewelcome.com (link para o netcraft)](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=websitewelcome.com) que também foi relatado (7/10 de grau de riso) ao acessar o `websitewelcome.com` apresenta a mensagem:

> For abuse issues related to the websitewelcome.com domain, please email your complaint with any relevant logs to abuse@websitewelcome.com

Recomendo que a primeira coisa que faça é trocar de empresa de hospedagem que "administra" (o que parece já ter sido feito).